# disable rack-mini-profiler in resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, rack-mini-profiler

Does anyone know how to disable rack-mini-profiler in my resque worker? I'm running on heroku so the environment is identical to my web server, however in my resque worker I don't want mini-profiler to instrument my database calls (it errors out occasionally). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the document [there](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby#available-options). There is an option (pre_authorize_cb) to enable/disable the profiler on any given request. Your "resque based" requests could have the callback return false to disable the profiler for them.

Comment: There is no request. This is just instrumenting the SQL as part of the gem. This is a resque worker.